# latest zen theme make the admin drop menu failed to work

Tags: theming

I am using the zen 7.5x, however when I tried it, the dropmenu for the admin doesn't work any more.

any one know how to solve this, is this because of javascript side?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you've confused the Drupal 7 "Toolbar" module (which is enabled by default on D7) with the behaviour of the familiar "Admin Menu" module?

If so, then you can get the behaviour you want by

- Install Admin Menu module
- Visit your modules page and *disable* "Toolbar", then *enable* "Admin Menu" (and if you like, "Admin Menu Toolbar"

Or, with Drush -

```
drush dl admin_menu && drush -y dis toolbar && drush -y en admin_menu_toolbar
```

(Enabling Admin Menu Toolbar style implicitly enables Admin Menu also.)